# "Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Markdown support"

Tags: android-studio, markdown

I was just about to update Android Studio to the version 3.1, but this warning made me to stop and think a little bit:

[image: "Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Markdown support"]

I tried to search for it and even read [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/android-studio-3-1.html) and [there](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com) again without finding nothing specifically related to the Markdown support.

I'd just like to know more about the consequences of ignoring this warning before updating and, if possible, to have more info about the Markdown support.

I thank you in advance for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's nothing much, just an usual warning indeed.

Just after I did a test update, the following report popped up:

[image: Markdown support]

Then it allowed me to briefly update the Markdown support to the version 2017.1.20170419 - 173.4301.21.